# como dar transition a imagenes cambiante mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

buen dia, tengo unas imagenes cambiantes mediante javascript pero me gustaria que tuviera un transition entre una imagen y otra.

Con css se hacerlo pero como estas se cambian mediante js no logro hacer que funcione... 
Mi pregunta es la siguiente: 
Se puede hacer como esta planteado el cambio de imagenes? o deberia colocar las imagenes en el html y con js jugar con las clases para realizar la transicion. 
Paso código para que vean lo que tengo

```
  /*--abre imagenes---*/
  function slide() {
  //hacemos visible el div
  document.getElementById("fotos").classList.toggle("abierto");
  // Cargamos una imagen 
  rotarImagenes();
  // Indicamos que cada 2 segundos cambie la imagen
  setInterval(rotarImagenes, 2000);
 }

 /*---slide fotos del proceso--*/
 /* Array con las imagenes y enlaces que se iran mostrando en la web*/

  var imagenes = new Array(
  ['https://img.blogs.es/anexom/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/42707058715_61bbdc578f_k.jpg', "procesos de fabricación junta especial 1"],
  ['https://i2.wp.com/currasysalgado.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/IMG_8358-e1518426140641.jpg?fit=500%2C333&ssl=1', "procesos de fabricación junta especial 2"],
  ['https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRShge5ab_to-h9y_aLorEym5rl0yHhXXUxrw2diw6YkeWjHItX', "procesos de fabricación junta especial 3"]);

  var contador = 0;

 /* Funcion para cambiar la imagen*/
  function rotarImagenes() {
  // cambiamos la imagen y el alt
  contador++
  document.getElementById("proceso").src = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][0];
  document.getElementById("proceso").alt = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][1];
}
section#juntas div#fotos {
  display: none;
}
section#juntas div#fotos.abierto {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  z-index: 900;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
}
section#juntas div#fotos.abierto figure img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
section#juntas div#fotos figure #cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: squareBold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
  color: #0b65ab;
}
<section id="juntas">
  <div id="video">
    <a href="#electricidad" onClick="slide()">MIRÁ NUESTROS PROCESOS DE FABRICACIÓN</a>
    <div id="flecha"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="fotos" class="">
    <figure>
      <img id="proceso" class="proceso" src="" alt="">
      <div id="cerrar" onClick="slide()">X</div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Gracias de antemano. Espero haber sido clara en lo que quiero lograr.

Comment: No termino de entender lo que deseas. Basicamente quieres que al cambiar la imagen haga una animacion como por ejemplo que cambie su tamaño?

Comment: quiero incorporar un transition de x segundos para que no sea tan brusco el cambio de una imagen a otra. que desaparezca una gradualmete y aparezca la siguiente gradualmente. en css suelo hacerlo con opacity de 0 a 1 segun la clase.... pero con js no se como se hace ( si es que se puede hacer)

Comment: Puedes realizar animaciones en css y luego agregar dichas clases con JS. Ya procedo a responder tu pregunta a ver si es lo que buscas , dame unos minutos.

Comment: Respondí tu pregunta con un efecto de opacidad sencillo. Ya ahí tu puedes implementar lo que desees

Answer (score 2):

Este seria el resultado final:

```js
  /*--abre imagenes---*/
  function slide() {
  //hacemos visible el div
  document.getElementById("fotos").classList.toggle("abierto");
  // Cargamos una imagen 
  rotarImagenes();
  // Indicamos que cada 2 segundos cambie la imagen
  setInterval(rotarImagenes, 4000);
 }

 /*---slide fotos del proceso--*/
 /* Array con las imagenes y enlaces que se iran mostrando en la web*/

  var imagenes = new Array(
  ['https://img.blogs.es/anexom/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/42707058715_61bbdc578f_k.jpg', "procesos de fabricación junta especial 1"],
  ['https://i2.wp.com/currasysalgado.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/IMG_8358-e1518426140641.jpg?fit=500%2C333&ssl=1', "procesos de fabricación junta especial 2"],
  ['https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRShge5ab_to-h9y_aLorEym5rl0yHhXXUxrw2diw6YkeWjHItX', "procesos de fabricación junta especial 3"]);

  var contador = 0;

 /* Funcion para cambiar la imagen*/
  function rotarImagenes() {
  // cambiamos la imagen y el alt
  contador++
const imagen = document.getElementById('proceso');
    imagen.style.opacity = "0";
setTimeout(() => {
  imagen.style.opacity = "1";
  imagen.src = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][0];
  imagen.alt = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][1];
  
}, 1000);
}
```

```css
section#juntas div#fotos {
  display: none;
}
section#juntas div#fotos.abierto {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  z-index: 900;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
}
section#juntas div#fotos.abierto figure img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
section#juntas div#fotos figure #cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: squareBold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
  color: #0b65ab;
}

.opacidad{
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<section id="juntas">
  <div id="video">
    <a href="#electricidad" onClick="slide()">MIRÁ NUESTROS PROCESOS DE FABRICACIÓN</a>
    <div id="flecha"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="fotos" class="">
    <figure>
      <img id="proceso" class="proceso opacidad" src="" alt="">
      <div id="cerrar" onClick="slide()">X</div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Que cambie y como lo hice?

Primero que todo a la imagen le agregue otra clase llamada '.opacidad' en la cual simplemente agrego un `transition` de 1 segundo.

```
.opacidad{
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

Ahora en el JS simplemente cambiamos un poco la función `rotarImagenes()`

Primero que todo cambie esta parte del código:

```
document.getElementById("proceso").src = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][0];
document.getElementById("proceso").alt = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][1];
```

Por esta:

```
const imagen = document.getElementById('proceso');
    imagen.style.opacity = "0";
setTimeout(() => {
  imagen.src = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][0];
  imagen.alt = imagenes[contador % imagenes.length][1];
  imagen.style.opacity = "1";
}, 1000);
```

Ahora, vamos por lineas:

1. Obtengo el elemento `IMG` del dom usando un tipo de variable `const` ya que no se va a re definir.
2. Luego cambio la opacidad de la imagen a 0 para luego proceder a cambiar de imagen y así hacer el efecto de desvanecimiento.
3. Agrega un `setTimeout` de 1 segundo que es la duración de nuestra animación.
4. Como en ese segundo que pasa la imagen no se va a observar cambiamos el `src` y el `alt` al que queremos.
5. Y por ultimo volvemos a aplicar la opacidad a 1 para que se visualice perfectamente la imagen.

También le añadí 2 segundos mas al `setInterval` para rotar las imagenes.